# permission denied error on hdfs hile using put command

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

While trying to use the put command to add patternsToSkip file to hdfs, I get an error saying: **Permission denied: user=root, access=WRITE, inode="/user":hdfs:hdfs:drwxr-xr-x**

In the image below, you can see the sequence of commands written along with the error:

[image: Commands & Error]

I tried to user access as biadmin, root, and even hdfs but with no luck! (details in the image)

please help me fix this error. Thanks folks.

Comment: (I don't see *why* the error message would report `…inode="/user"…` without funny links/mounts: which file systems are `/home/biadmin`, `/home/biadmin/labfiles` and `/home/biadmin/labfiles/..` in?) Why do you want "to put" to `labfiles/..`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason, it is giving permission issue is because you are trying to put the file inside /user directory in hdfs since you are using 2 dots in put statement. You need to login as supergroup to access or copy file inside that particular directory.

What i would suggest is try running below commands to copy file to hdfs.
Target with one dot

```
hadoop fs -put patternsToSkip .
```

OR

Giving complete target directory path

```
hadoop fs -put patternsToSkip /user/<instance_name>/output
```